# Why does my screen blank out every night at the same time?

Tags: video, screen, lock-screen

It's curious. Every night at around 0300 my screen goes black for one or two seconds, then it comes back on. No lockout, no login screen, everything is as normal afterwards.

I do not have any screensaver enabled. I do, however have it set to poweroff the monitor after being inactive for one hour. This has always worked flawlessly.

I am not using dual monitors. It's basically a bare-bones installation with only my Firefox and Thunderbird profiles restored.

The computer has typically been on for eight to twelve hours at this point. I'm usually just surfing the web when this happens, but sometimes I might be on LibreOffice writing a letter, or anything else I might be doing on the system. No matter what I'm doing, it's like clockwork.

I've been using Ubuntu since 12.04. I'm currently on 16.04. I've been using fresh installs with every upgrade, and it's always been the same. Is it the system doing a thingy? Maybe it's doing a check on the whatnot in the doo-dad? Is it a hootenanny in the diddly-bob?

Comment: What happens if you change the (bios) clock time?

Comment: Is it at the time `cron.daily` runs? Do `grep cron.daily /var/log/syslog` and `grep cron.daily /var/log/syslog.1`, and look at the time stamps.

Comment: @Jos I ran your commands and it shows that cron.daily ran today at 11:28, which is exactly 5 min after I turned the computer on this morning.

Comment: @JamesK K I'll change the BIOS right now and report back tonight.

Thank you both for your comments.